# appending a piece of code to input field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add an element to the input field if the condition meets: i tried using below but nothing seems happening, i tried with the following code which to me seems to a good one but something is missing and what i am so lost

```
$("#anc").load('get.cfm?new=' + Math.random()).appendTo('#anc');
```

I tried getting it to work but this is somewhat not adding the attribute to the input field...

the get.cfm has the value of

```
disabled="false"
```

what can i pass to fix this issue

Comment: what error you are getting in the console.

Comment: my code is correct, i don't why it did not worked at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add attribute, use .attr(attrName, attrValue)

```
.$("#anc").load("...", function(response) {
      //if the response is "disabled='true'";
      var keyValue = response.split("=");
      $('#anc').attr(keyValue[0],keyValue[1])
  }
```